How to fix python installation on windows 10?
On windows 10 my python installation does not seem to work anymore. When I run python I get an error
Program 'python' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

I can run the command py, but when I try to run a script with it it does not find numpy for example. Installing numpy with
 pip install numpy

seems to work(?) but when I try to run the same script again I still get the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

How to fix the python installation?
python.exe seem to work but not python...
Maybe it is related to an unsuccessful install of cygwin?
On a powershell terminal the command
which python

returns:
/usr/bin/python

Again, I am on windows 10. Unfortunately ...

Have you actually installed Python and added the directory to your PATH variable?

How to find the location of the python installation?

Sounds like you have not specifically installed Python. You should that way you know the installation directory.

It worked for a year without problems. Not sure what could have broken the installation, maybe because I was trying to use cygwin?

When I run which python in a Powershell terminal I get /usr/bin/python! What the hell is going on???

I had to remove all relations to that non-working cygwin stuff for the environment variables. That seem to have worked

I’m voting to close this question because “I had to remove all relations to that non-working cygwin stuff”
